# Qt Designer Point Size drops to -1 when adding "font-size" in stylesheet

Tags: qt, fonts, qt-designer

I have an issue in Qt Designer (Ver 5.6.2).
I have checked all StyleSheets, they are all empty exept for the one for the MainWindow where everything is written in.
There is no "font, font-size, font-family etc."
if i add like

```
#label1 {font-size: 10px;}
```

and run the app, following appears in the console:

```
QFont::setPointSize: Point size <= 0 (-1), must be greater than 0
```

the good news is, that the font size gets to 10 px but I want to get rid of the Error.
also in my QtDesigner App i cant increase the PointSize manually, it always stays on -1, even if you try to increase it, 
[image: Screenshot]
in the ui / xml file following appears:

```
<property name="font">
   <font>
    <pointsize>-1</pointsize>
   </font>
  </property>
```

Does someone have the same issue? How can i get rid of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of it by either:

1. Editing the `.ui` file to remove the silly property value `<pointsize>-1</pointsize>`.
2. Restoring the point size to the default, non-overridden value - see the screenshot you provided, click on the "Point Size" field, then click on the little revert back-arrow that will appear there.

The stylesheets don't figure in this.