# QtDesigner setting font sizes to -1

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt5, qt-designer

I have used qt designer to make a ui files which I convert using pyuic5. However, the problem I am having is inside qt designer itself.

### The problem

The issue I am having is when using the style sheet (set in qt designer) property of 'font-size: 36px' (or any pixel size). When I set this font-size property in the designer, the 'font' property in the designer itself is set to -1 automatically and cannot be changed. This gives the following error while the program is running `QFont::setPointSize: Point size <= 0 (-1), must be greater than 0`

No problems are encountered while running the program, but the error message appears very frequently which I'd like to avoid.

This [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45841116/qt-designer-point-size-drops-to-1-when-adding-font-size-in-stylesheet) suggests removing the font property from the ui files themselves but I would like to avoid this if possible as I am afraid this will cause problems down the line. I have tried clicking on the option to reset the font as it suggests but the button is greyed out (it is already at default but still on -1). The answer here also says it is unrelated to the style sheets but if I remove the font-size from the style sheet the font is no longer stuck at -1. I have confirmed that this happens on different files and it happens when the stylesheet is set.

### My question

So, my question is can I fix this error in the qt designer or will I have to remove the font property from my ui files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fix for my problem is, quite simply, using `pt` instead of `px` in the style sheet. Yep, that's it. Now to adjust all my font sizes again.

I don't know why px causes a problem in the qt designer stylesheet so if anybody reading this knows, please do share as I couldn't find an answer for that.

Comment: QtDesigner is limited in many areas to what it understands. Educated guess: QtDesigner tries to be clever about translating your stylesheet into properties. The parser returns -1 for font size because it was supposed to return pt, which it can't. The code that takes its result to rewrite the font property misses a check for -1. Overall, it's a bug and you could file a bug report with the Qt project. My experience with filing bugs with them however is mixed to negative regarding their response (or lack thereof).

Comment: If your experience is negative I think I'll leave it but I wanted this here if anyone else happens to be struggling with the same thing as this took me a while to figure out. And yeah your guess is probably right, thanks for replying

Comment: [@ypnos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/21974/ypnos) someone down voted the question above, but didn't suggest an improvement, do you know how I can improve it in any way?

Comment: I don't know, some people just love to do that. I wouldn't spend too much thought onto this.

Comment: Ok, thank you, that was a weird one after 4 months